Long running PS 5.1 (Win10) script causes sub-process to hang
I have a script that executes another application (an automated test application) as part of a scheduled job.  During the execution of the test the powershell script is on a wait, monitoring for process end of the test so that it can log the test result and move onto the next test.
The test takes 2+ hours to run.  During this time the test software will hang / suspend / pause (generally after about 20 minutes).
When the test software gets stuck, killing the PowerShell process in task manager will cause the test application to immediately resume without issue, indicating that something is happening to powershell process that is affecting the test process as it is a child-process.
I do NOT believe this relates to the powershell setting to do with text selection, as I have already made that change with no effect.  Powershell is also not sitting waiting for a keypress, as this behaviour is seen even running outside of the scheduled task.
I uses a system.Diagnostics.Process object with a ProcessStartInfo to launch the test software with arguments.  I utilise Process.WaitForExit to wait for the test to complete and test application to close to analyse the log file it produces.
Any thoughts on the cause and fix of the powershell hang?
many thanks
Edit:
i reran this process today having previously  let the powershell script just end after the sub-process was launched.. powershell froze after 1hr 20 causing hte sub-process to freeze / pause also... killed piwersjell... sub-priocess strted again carrying on from where it was; a true "pause" of sorts

Are you redirecting stdin / stdout? From memory, it's really easy to cause deadlocks if you don't do it exactly right (and I can't remember what "exactly right" means :-S)... If you can add a slimmed down code sample (ideally that can reproduce the issue) it might help diagnose...

@mclayton at one point i did try this as a desperation to get insight, but ultimately no - just process.start and then process.waitforexit

Kind of need to see some sample code really - without that it's hard to say. Can you trim your script down to half a dozen lines that reproduce the issue (test exactly what you post to make sure it's reproducible)?
